# terminology question: Is there a generic name for the set of probabilities corresponding to quantiles

Tags: distributions, terminology, quantiles

Given a set $P_i$ of probabilities and a Cumulative Distribution Function of $X$ you can find the set $X_i$ of values of $X$ corresponding to $P_i$. The $X_i$ are the "quantiles". Is there an equivalent generic term for referring to the $P_i$ corresponding to a given set of $X_i$?

You could refer to them as the CDF but in standard use that refers to the $P_i$ corresponding to *all* the $X_i$ rather than some designated subset of interest.

In the absence of a pre-existing name I'll probably use some awful phrase like "Corresponding Cumulative Probabilities" (abbreviated as CCP and pronounced "soviets").

Comment: Aren't these usually just called the "percents" when the quantiles are referred to as percentiles?

Comment: @whuber Do you have any feeling for how widely used that terminology is (percents/percentiles)? I ran the query past my office-mates before posting and nobody knew a generic term. My concern with "percents" as terminology is that it is tied to a specific set of probabilities. In my line of work we frequently use deciles - percents/deciles doesn't work so well, and decs/deciles is jut mystifying. I like probtiles/quantiles because it is an obvious derivation, there is no chance of confusion with "probtiles" being used in some other sense (unlike "percents") and it is completely generic.

Comment: It's common--search the Web. Some authors have attempted to refine this a little; *e.g.,* Freedman, Pisani, & Purves (*Statistics,* WW Norton & Co.) state (in the context of a group of test scores), "A *percentile* is a score; in example 10, the 95th percentile is a score of 700.  A *percentile rank*, however, is a percent: if you score 700, your percentile rank is 95%." "Probtile" is so etymologically bizarre (and strangely pronounced) I doubt it will ever get any currency.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. Now that I know where to look I can see that "quantile rank" is also [used](https://scholar.vt.edu/access/content/group/43c8db00-e78f-4dcd-826c-ac236fb59e24/common/tables/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I guessed that "probtile" sounded like a good analogue to "quantile" and did a search to see if probtile exists in the wild, and it does!

"Probtile" is used in mathematical finance to mean the probability corresponding to a quantile. However, the word doesn't seem to be widely used - mostly in the writings of Gilles Zumbach of RiskMetrics Group ([This 2006 paper](http://www.risk.net/digital_assets/4801/jor_v9n2a4.pdf) introduces the term "probtile".) This suggests that few people feel the need for the concept and that different terms for the same concept may have been invented in different fields.

I would interested to hear of any alternatives to probtile.